# Get the index of a certain value in an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$list = array('string1', 'string2', 'string3');
```

I want to get the index for a given value (i.e. `1` for `string2` and `2` for `string3`)

All I want is the position of the strings in the array

- string1 is 0
- string2 is 1
- string3 is 2

How to achieve this?

Comment: this is old .... but I wold like to know why: _"I tried array_search but it was no use"_

Comment: If you have an associative array, as I did, this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3365793/470749

Answer (score 219, accepted):

`array_search` is the way to do it.

> `array_search ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] ) : mixed`

From the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php):

```
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');

$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
$key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
```

You could loop over the array manually and find the index but why do it when there's a function for that. This function always returns a key and it will work well with associative and normal arrays.

Comment: This returns the key, not the index. In your example the key is conveniently the index of the value.

Comment: @smink, the OP's array is a non-associative array, so it works fine.

Comment: sorry, i didn't specify the type of array. The array i use is a multi-dimensional array please see my answer for the solution

Comment: I have this type of array : [ 0 => { id : 1, name : something}, 1 => {.....}, ...].
is this possible to find key/index like array_search("name"=>something,$array) ?

Comment: How about if the array has child ?

Answer (score 25):

If you're only doing a few of them (and/or the array size is large), then you were on the right track with array_search:

```
$list = array('string1', 'string2', 'string3');
$k = array_search('string2', $list); //$k = 1;
```

If you want all (or a lot of them), a loop will prob do you better:

```
foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . " in " . $key . ", ";
}
// Prints "string1 in 0, string2 in 1, string3 in 2, "
```

Answer (score 20):

The problem is that you don't have a numerical index on your array.
Using array_values() will create a zero indexed array that you can then search using array_search() bypassing the need to use a for loop.

```
$list = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'];
$index = array_search('string2',array_values($list));
```

Answer (score 16):

Other folks have suggested `array_search()` which gives the key of the array element where the value is found.  You can ensure that the array keys are contiguous integers by using `array_values()`:

```
$list = array(0=>'string1', 'foo'=>'string2', 42=>'string3');
$index = array_search('string2', array_values($list));
print "$index\n";

// result: 1
```

You said in your question that `array_search()` was no use.  Can you explain why?  What did you try and how did it not meet your needs?

Answer (score 10):

// or considering your array structure:

```
$array = array(
  'string1' => array('a' => '', 'b' => '', 'c' => ''),
  'string2' => array('a' => '', 'b' => '', 'c' => ''),
  'string3' => array('a' => '', 'b' => '', 'c' => ''),
);
```

// you could just

```
function findIndexOfKey($key_to_index,$array){
  return array_search($key_to_index,array_keys($array));
}
```

// executed

```
print "\r\n//-- Method 1 --//\r\n";
print '#index of: string1 = '.findIndexofKey('string1',$array)."\r\n";
print '#index of: string2 = '.findIndexofKey('string2',$array)."\r\n";
print '#index of: string3 = '.findIndexofKey('string3',$array)."\r\n";
```

// alternatively

```
print "\r\n//-- Method 2 --//\r\n";
print '#index of: string1 = '.array_search('string1',array_keys($array))."\r\n";
print '#index of: string2 = '.array_search('string2',array_keys($array))."\r\n";
print '#index of: string3 = '.array_search('string3',array_keys($array))."\r\n";
```

// recursersively

```
print "\r\n//-- Method 3 --//\r\n";
foreach(array_keys($array) as $key => $value){
  print '#index of: '.$value.' = '.$key."\r\n";
}
```

// outputs

```
//-- Method 1 --//
#index of: string1 = 0
#index of: string2 = 1
#index of: string3 = 2

//-- Method 2 --//
#index of: string1 = 0
#index of: string2 = 1
#index of: string3 = 2

//-- Method 3 --//
#index of: string1 = 0
#index of: string2 = 1
#index of: string3 = 2
```

Comment: This answer has deviated too far from the asked question.  The question is not talking about associative arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Try the array_keys PHP function.

```
$key_string1 = array_keys($list, 'string1');
```

Comment: aren't those parameters [reversed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)?

Comment: @ashleedawg No you have misread, `array_keys` is different to `array_search`

Answer (score 1):

Could you be a little more specific?

```
$key = array_search('string2',$list)
```

works fine for me.  Are you trying to accomplish something more complex?