# php - get numeric index of associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array and I need to find the numeric position of a key.
I could loop through the array manually to find it, but is there a better way build into PHP?

```
$a = array(
  'blue'   => 'nice',
  'car'    => 'fast',
  'number' => 'none'
);

// echo (find numeric index of $a['car']); // output: 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the index of a certain value in an array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959222/get-the-index-of-a-certain-value-in-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 307, accepted):

```
echo array_search("car",array_keys($a));
```

Comment: Does PHP guarantee the order of an associative array?

Comment: @KevinBurke It's not going to re-order it unless you use a sort function.  Not sure what sort of guarantee you're looking for, but it's not like the JavaScript model where there is no static order to associative arrays.

Comment: The indexes given by "array_keys" will not necessarily match the index of the original array. For example, if you have altered the array by using "unset" or a number of other functions, there will be a gap left in the index of the original array, but array_keys will produce a new array.

Comment: This DOES NOT work if the associative array is mixed, for `array("val1", "val2", "car" => "val3")` it will produce `0`, which is wrong...

Comment: How is this any different from [@quantamSoup's answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3365780/6368005)

Answer (score 38):

```
$blue_keys = array_search("blue", array_keys($a));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Answer (score 5):

While Fosco's answer is not wrong there is a **case to be considered** with this one: mixed arrays. Imagine I have an array like this:

```
$a = array(
  "nice",
  "car" => "fast",
  "none"
);
```

Now, PHP allows this kind of syntax but it has one problem: if I run Fosco's code I get `0` **which is wrong** for me, but why this happens?
Because when doing comparisons between strings and integers **PHP converts strings to integers** (and this is kinda stupid in my opinion), so when `array_search()` searches for the index it stops at the first one because apparently `("car" == 0)` **is true**.
Setting `array_search()` to strict mode won't solve the problem because then `array_search("0", array_keys($a))` would return false even if an element with index 0 exists.
So my solution just converts all indexes from `array_keys()` to strings and then compares them correctly:

```
echo array_search("car", array_map("strval", array_keys($a)));
```

Prints `1`, which is correct.

**EDIT:**
As Shaun pointed out in the comment below, the same thing applies to the index value, if you happen to search for an int index like this:

```
$a = array(
  "foo" => "bar",
  "nice",
  "car" => "fast",
  "none"
);
$ind = 0;
echo array_search($ind, array_map("strval", array_keys($a)));
```

You will always get `0`, which is wrong, so the solution would be to cast the index (if you use a variable) to a string like this:

```
$ind = 0;
echo array_search((string)$ind, array_map("strval", array_keys($a)));
```

Comment: When passing a variable, you should also cast it as a string, as passing zero to an associative array would have the same negative effect. For example: `var_dump(array_search(0, array_map("strval", array_keys($a))));` will always output `int (0)`, rather than `bool (false)`.

Comment: @ShaunCockerill right! Updated my answer, thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 3):

The solution with array_search would be really heavy, and it's unnecessary to use straight search in this situation.

Much better solution would be:

```
$keyIndexOfWhichYouAreTryingToFind = 'c';
$array = [
    'a' => 'b',
    'c' => 'd'
];
$index = array_flip(array_keys($array))[$keyIndexOfWhichYouAreTryingToFind];
```

This type of search would have much better performance on big arrays.

Comment: array flip is not O(n) = 1. Although your solution is better in terms of performance,, which I vote as a better solution. it is not truly O(n) = 1

Answer (score 2):

```
  $a = array(
      'blue' => 'nice',
      'car' => 'fast',
      'number' => 'none'
  );  
var_dump(array_search('car', array_keys($a)));
var_dump(array_search('blue', array_keys($a)));
var_dump(array_search('number', array_keys($a)));
```

Answer (score 1):

All solutions based on array_keys don't work for mixed arrays. Solution is simple:

```
echo array_search($needle,array_keys($haystack), true);
```

From php.net:
If the third parameter strict is set to TRUE then the array_search() function will search for identical elements in the haystack. This means it will also perform a strict type comparison of the needle in the haystack, and objects must be the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

a solution i came up with... probably pretty inefficient in comparison tho Fosco's solution:

```
 protected function getFirstPosition(array$array, $content, $key = true) {

  $index = 0;
  if ($key) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == $content) {
     return $index;
    }
    $index++;
   }
  } else {
   foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == $content) {
     return $index;
    }
    $index++;
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, PHP has thousands of builtin functions for a reason.  These are *usually* much faster than equivalent logic written out the long way in PHP code.

Comment: This is probably faster than `array_search`, which does a sort first and so it painfully slow.

Comment: Ah, but the built in code is precompiled, and the search will most likely be a binary search (assuming it does sort items first).