# How to get position in a php associative array?

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php - get numeric index of associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365766/php-get-numeric-index-of-associative-array)

```
$array = ('a'=>'a', 'b'=>'b');
foreach($array as $key => $value ){
   //echo $position ( 1,2 )
}
```

Can I get the position in the array with a simple function ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$i = 0;
$array = ('a'=>'a', 'b'=>'b');
foreach($array as $key => $value ){
   $i++;
   echo $i;
}
```

Comment: You can skip one line of code by using `echo ++$i;`. See [Incrementing/Decrementing Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('a'=>'a', 'b'=>'b');
for ($x = 0; $x < count($array);$x++)
        echo $x."<br >";
```