# PDO and binding Dynamic Associative Array Parameters

Tags: php, database, pdo

I am attempting to properly bind parameters to a statement with the `Function` below.   I am passing in an associative array, `value=>datatype`.

I am getting an error though while attempting this: `Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in db.class.php on line 69 Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in db.class.php on line 69`

Line 69 is the `for` line in `Function`

How do I fix this?  And/Or should I even bother doing it like this?

Here's `Function`

```
protected function ConvertParams($stmt, $params){
    $parrs = $params;
    if(is_array($parrs)){
        $parrCt = count($parrs);
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($parrs);
        echo '</pre>';
        echo '<hr />';
        for($i = 0; $i < $parrCt; ++$i){
            switch ($parrs[$i][1]){
                case 'string':
                    $stmt->bindParam($i + 1, $parrs[$i][0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    break;
                case 'int':
                    $stmt->bindParam($i + 1, $parrs[$i][0], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    break;
                case 'boolean':
                    $stmt->bindParam($i + 1, $parrs[$i][0], PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
                    break;
                case 'lob':
                    $stmt->bindParam($i + 1, $parrs[$i][0], PDO::PARAM_LOB);
                    break;
                default:
                    $stmt->bindParam($i + 1, $parrs[$i][0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the `array`:

```
$db->Params = array('%a%'=>'string', '%Welcome%'=>'string');
```

Please assume that I am connecting to the db correctly, and that the query properly executes (minus this bindParam issue).

Comment: Can you please post the sample code where this function is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need neither "proper way of binding" nor whole this function at all. 
Just pass an array of parameters straight to execute:

```
$params = array('%a%', '%Welcome%');
$stmt->execute($params);
```

it will dramatically shorten your code without any drawbacks.

Please keep your code clean and simple.
Useless complication will make it hard to support and maintain.

Comment: `Useless complication will make it hard to support and maintain.` =)   I agree, I come from a Classic ASP background, so I assumed parameterizing would be the proper way to do it.   Is there any setbacks to doing how you posted?

Comment: The **only** case known to me is listed in the [pdo tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) under `"PDO prepared statements and LIMIT"` title.

Answer (score 0):

My first post... I could be wrong here, but I believe there is no [0] or [1] index of $parrs as you're passing it with named index of '%a%' and '%Welcome%'.

You could try replacing the [0] and [1] with %a% and %Welcome% respectively, or using numeric indexes for the array.

- http://php.net/array_search
- http://php.net/array_keys
- [php - get numeric index of associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365766/php-get-numeric-index-of-associative-array)

Comment: it is needed the way I have it...   Value => Datatype

Comment: I'm not saying you have to change your array. But you can't reference [0] if the array doesn't have numerical indexes. Call it by its named index, or get the numerical indexes per my links. Thanks for reading and giving me a -1