# find numeric key of associative index of array in array

Tags: php

I can't understand how to get numeric index of "Index1" in such a structure:

```
$arr = array('Index','Index1' => array("one","two","three"),'Index2');
```

i'm trying to use array_search like so:

```
$index = array_search("Index1",$arr);
```

but it doesn't work;
Thanks

Comment: `Index1` doesn't have a numeric index ([see for yourself](http://codepad.org/4vyRQYbd))

Comment: The index is `Index1`. There's no "numeric index" for a string index.

Comment: You could also write the array as `array(0 => 'Index', 'Index1' => .., 1 => 'Index2')` and produce the exact same structure

Comment: look at this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365766/php-get-numeric-index-of-associative-array

Comment: indeed, it doesn't exist @kingkero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, there is no numeric index for that element, as its key is a string.

However if you just want to find its position in the array:

```
$position = array_search("Index1",array_keys($arr),true);
```

Comment: $position becomes 0 whick is not correct

Comment: @TraktorFieldwork Oops, forgot to set the 3rd parameter. See working edit