# get numeric index of associatve array without specifying the key name

Tags: php, arrays

So I came to a point where I need to check a value inside an array:

```
Array [
    'oneName' => [
        'val'   => 'str',
        'price' => 'int'
    ],
    'twoName' => [
        'val'   => 'str',
        'price' => 'int'
    ]
]
```

however, these `oneName`, `twoName` key names are dynamically created from another script. I need to check the value of `twoName['price']` (for example) in an if statement which is fine. I came across this SO post regarding a similar topic: [php - get numeric index of associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365766/php-get-numeric-index-of-associative-array) but this is done by specifying the key name and returning the index value based on that. How can I access twoName via a numeric index without specifying the key name? Or am I asking the impossible?

Comment: You may use `array_values($your_arr)` before access it through numeric values..

Comment: @FrayneKonok will this work for multi-dimensional arrays too? :)

Comment: For your array this will works and output will be like: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [val] => str [price] => int ) [1] => Array ( [val] => str [price] => int ) )`

Comment: @FrayneKonok awesome, I just looked at the PHP documentation for the function and yeah looks like it's ok, not to fussed about order of array - if you turn it into an answer, I'd be happy to accept / upvote

Comment: To downvoter - I'm ok with it, but please leave an explanation so I can improve. A downvote without explanation is just as bad as a bad question - no one learns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get numeric index of associative array without specifying the key name you need to use the [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function.

Example:

```
$arr = [
    'oneName' => [
        'val'   => 'str',
        'price' => 'int'
    ],
    'twoName' => [
        'val'   => 'str',
        'price' => 'int'
    ]
];

$arr = array_values($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [val] => str
            [price] => int
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [val] => str
            [price] => int
        )

)
```