# Problem with unset in "Post" array using timber

Tags: php, twig, timber

I'm creating a Wordpress blog application using timber and twig.
The problem is that i want to select all post except for one
This is what I have now:

```
$context = Timber::get_context();
$context['post'] = new Timber\Post(); //the one we don't want

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'post_tag' => $context['post']->post_tag
);

$context['relevant'] = Timber::get_posts($args);//the ones we want

Timber::render(array('single-' . $post->post_type . '.twig', 'single.twig'), $context);
```

context['post']: contains one single post.

context['relevant'] contains all the posts with te same tag as context['post']

what i exactly want is: if the context['post'] element, is included in the context['relevant'], I want it removed and put in an other post in it instead.

Is there any way to do this?

Any help is much appreciated and thanks in advance.

**SOVED**

actually really easy,
the only thing I had to do was to get het index of the array and then unset is.

```
$a = array_search($context['post'], $context['relevant']);

unset($context['relevant'][$a]);
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking/trying to do... What does `$context['relevant']` and `$context['post']` contains?

Comment: is this more clear?

Comment: If you can precisely describe what your code should do, what keeps you from writing it?

Comment: please verify once your Wordpress version with PHP version compatibility.

Comment: beacause I get errors @NicoHaase

Comment: my Wordpress and PHP are both compatible @PrinceKumarDwivedi

Comment: Your description is still rather unclear. If `context['post']` contains a full WP post object, it makes no sense to try and use that as an array index (referring to `$context['relevant'][$context['post']]`). _“context['relevant'] contains all the posts”_ - in what exact structure? Like using the post id as index, or - something else?

Comment: So you want to remove a specific post from your array with posts? Then you would need to search the array first for the right [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959222/get-the-index-value-of-an-array-in-php) to unset

Comment: makes sense, i've edited the question so it is more clearly @04FS

Comment: If you "get errors", can you share them? Any error message would help to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

use isset function to not throwing errors

```
if(isset($context['relevant'][$context['post']])){
    unset($context['relevant'][$context['post']]);
}
```

Comment: im still getting the following error: Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty